# Show password checkbox in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how do i show or hide password on click of a checkbox?
this is my model class-

```
    public partial class user
{
    [Required]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

And in my View i have done this -

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

So now i want to add a checkbox that would show and hide the password.

i searched that it can be done with the help of javascript easily in a webform by changing the 'type' from 'password' to 'text' on the click of checkbox but here in mvc i have mentioned my DataType in the model class. so is there any way that i can change it to text using jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do the same thing in ASP.NET MVC as well since it is client side javascript. Razor uses the attributes to render input elements. Once it is rendered to the browser, you can do anything on the rendered output with client side javascript.

Assuming you have a checkbox with id `showPass`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "form-control" } )
<input type="checkbox" id="showPass"/>
```

Now, listen to the `change` event on this checkbox and if it is true, simply update the input element's `type` attribute value.

```
$(function() {

    $("#showPass").change(function() {
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");           
        if (checked) {
            $("#password").attr("type", "text");
        } else {
            $("#password").attr("type", "password");
        }
    });

});
```